# Discord JS - How do you get the status of a user within a Guild?

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to get the online status of any given user within a guild that the bot is in?

Currently I can get the online status of message author. However, I want to be able to get any users online status such as the following:

```
const member = client.getMemeber(ID OR USERNAME);
const online_status = member.presence.status;
```

And that it returns `null, online, dnd, idle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a member,you want a guild first:
`const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId);`, then you can get the member: `const member = guild.members.cache.get(userId);`. Alternatively, you can get a user directly from the client: `const user = client.users.cache.get(userId);`, but a user doesn't have a presense property.

```js
const member = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)?.members.cache.get(userId);
console.log(member.presense.status);
```